# What is causing the segmentation fault in this code? Code is in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf, function-call, variable-length-array

I've been working in C lately and I've started working with arrays recently. Can you help me identify what's causing the issue here? I'm fairly certain the function inputArray is, but I cannot figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inputArray(int array[], int size);

int main() {
    int arraySize;
    printf("Enter size of array: \n");
    scanf("%d", &arraySize);
    int myArray[arraySize];
    inputArray(myArray[arraySize], arraySize);

    return 0;
}


void inputArray(int array[], int size){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++){
        printf("Enter value for array: \n");
        scanf("%d", array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even with standard settings, the compiler gives you warnings that explains the problem well. Warnings are there to help you. Read them.

Comment: foo(type bar) cannot change 'bar' because arguments are COPIED into parameters. Any call that must  change variables in the caller, (eg. scanf), must therefore be provided with address arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This call

```
inputArray(myArray[arraySize], arraySize);
```

is incorrect. The compiler shall issue a message that the passed first argument has no the type int *. You are passing a non-existent element of the array with the index arraySize.

You need to write

```
inputArray(myArray, arraySize);
```

Also you have to write

```
scanf("%d", &array[i]);
```

or

```
scanf("%d", array + i);
```

instead of

```
scanf("%d", array[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to pass in `myarray[arraysize]` into your helper function. Just `myarray`